# google maps infinite line / increase length or lat lng calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates

Hey there i´m trying to find a way to just increase the length of a line without changing the orientation

i tried this with Polyline

```
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 37.4419, lng: -122.1419},
    zoom: 8
  });
    var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), new google.maps.LatLng(37.4519, -122.1519)],
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 10,
    geodesic: true,
    map: map
});
}
```

and it works as expected

[image: example]

but i rather want it like

[image: example2]

or

[image]

i only have the two coordinates from first example

it should be geodesic and theoreticaly idealy arround the globe back at same start so it will be like endless

i also tried to find out a way to calculate the some more far coordinates but searching is a mess because everboidy want to be found for caluclating distances. 
so having two coordinates following the "line-through orientation" of but have high distance like some thousand kilometers pls let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Google Maps Javascript API Geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) to compute the heading of the line and extend it an arbitrarily long distance along that heading.

**code snippet::**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 37.4419,
      lng: -122.1419
    },
    zoom: 8
  });
  var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), new google.maps.LatLng(37.4519, -122.1519)],
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 10,
    geodesic: true,
    map: map
  });
  // extend line from each end along its existing heading
  // pick 20e6 meters as an arbitrary length
  var lineHeading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(line.getPath().getAt(0), line.getPath().getAt(1));
  var newPt0 = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(line.getPath().getAt(0), 20000000, lineHeading);
  line.getPath().insertAt(0, newPt0);
  var newPt1 = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(line.getPath().getAt(1), 20000000, lineHeading + 180);
  line.getPath().push(newPt1);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```